# Get Android PRL Version

Tags: android

I have been looking for a while now, I have been unable to find a way to get the PRL version of the phone programmatically. If someone could lend me a hand that would be awesome.

Comment: I dont think you can get this through any api, most of the phones will have different mechanisms based upon RIL and will be restricted to Radio process

Comment: @nandeesh It shows in the code for the android settings app KEY_PRL_VERSION="prl_version" is there any way to read that?

Comment: unless your phone is rooted, i dont think you can read it. That data is private to Settings app

Comment: @nandeesh Okay, I would like to keep looking I thought that it could be easily done, didn't know it was going to take me all day to find it. Thanks for your help and if you happen to know how I would read it with a rooted phone at least that information would be helpful as well.